# Why is it adding the variables wrong?

Tags: java, decimal

I'm using Java but, it's not adding the amount correctly. I'll give my parts of my code.

```
final double taxrate=.08;
Map<String,Integer> Priceproduct= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
Priceproduct.put("shoes",(int) 50.00);      
Priceproduct.put("shirts",(int) 30.00);
Priceproduct.put("shorts",(int) 75.00);
Priceproduct.put("caps",(int) 15.00);
Priceproduct.put("jackets",(int) 100.00);

System.out.print("\n Enter the product: ");
String product=keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print( "\n Enter the quantity of the product");
int quantity=keyboard.nextInt();

int cost= Priceproduct.get(product)*quantity;
int tax= (int) (cost*taxrate);
System.out.print("\n tax=" +cost*taxrate+"");

int TotalBill= cost+tax;
System.out.print("\nTotal="+cost+ + +tax+"");
```

When it adds the cost and tax (those two are correct) it's gets the completely wrong answer.
For example 3 shirts= 90, the tax equals 7.2, and the total becomes 907.

Do I need to use DecimalFormat or something else?

Comment: You are concatanating the numbers, not adding them. Take a look at operator precedence, and feel free to use parentheses every now and then

Comment: Try printing TotalBill

Comment: He also needs to store tax as a double, not an int.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
System.out.print("\nTotal="+cost+ + +tax+"");
```

to this:

```
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Total=" + (cost + tax));
```

(The problem is that `+` is left-associative, so without parentheses around your addition, `"a" + b + c` means `("a" + b) + c`, which does string-concatenation at both stages.)

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an operation alongside a string Java will perform that operation as if the operands were strings.

In your `System.out.println()` calls you don't need to redo the calculations, just print out the variables "tax" and "totalBill". (This will solve the problem of printing '907')

You will only ever get integer values because you are using `int` type for everything. If you want to have decimals to indicate cents you should be using type `double`.